# \textwidth in tabular does not add up

Tags: tables

I had the understanding that the constant `\textwidth` is the width of text from the left margin to the right margin. I have been using the same as width specifier in my tables with paragraph. However, even if the widths all add up to `\textwidth`, the width of the table is quite a bit more than the text above and below it. Could you please explain the bahaviour?

Here's the MWE

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 11pt]{article} 
\usepackage[a4paper, top=1in, bottom=1in,, left=1in, right=1.5in, showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1]
\noindent\begin{tabular}[]{|p{0.05\textwidth}|p{0.6\textwidth}|p{0.35\textwidth}|}
        \hline
        \textbf {Sr. No.} & \textbf {Item} & \textbf {Projected Budget} \\ \hline
        1. & Test 123 column 2 & 123456789 \\ \hline
        2. & test456 Column 2 & 987654321 \\ \hline
    \end{tabular}   
\end{document}
```

Comment: Yes, you are right, the answer there addresses my concern. How do I deal with the same? delete the question?

Comment: The question is now marked as duplicate, thus the question will not show up in the unanswered questions anymore. You can also keep the question. If someone finds this question first, then he will find the solution via the duplicate link.